# App Installation failed after upgrade to XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

My apps will no long install on my devices in my development environment after installing Xcode 8 with the error : App installation failed “A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.”

I’ve seen quite a few questions here on the subject and I’ve slowly gone through all the answers but to no avail.  I thought it might have been ios10 but I keep one of my devices at ios9, that one don’t work either.

What I’ve done :

- I’ve switched between Xcode automatically handling signing and doing
  it manually, setting all the profiles to “Development”.
- I’ve deleted all the provisioning profiles and redownloaded them.
- I’ve tried going to developer portal, manually regenerating the
  provisioning profiles and using them.
- When I check the info next to the XCode managed profile, under
  “Devices”, my current device is listed.
- Turned on and off the Push notification services. (I don’t use push
  notifications).
- Also disabled push notification services on my App ID in the
  development portal.
- Removed the provisioning profiles from the devices themselves in the
  Devices Window.
- Deleted all old certificates in my keychain.
- Updated all my cocoa pods.
- Restarted countless times and did many of the different steps in
  different orders.
- I recently had to turn on keychain sharing as my app no longer wanted
  to retrieve an access token used for oAuth from the keychain, but
  turning that on or off had no effect either.
- Other than the recently changed keychain access, I have no other
  entitlements.
- With the keychain access, I also created an app group in the
  development portal and made sure it was set for my keychain group. 
  No difference

I’ve been stuck on this a day now and it’s really pushing back my next release as I have to test on real devices, the error message is frustratingly vague when everything seems in place, am I missing a log file somewhere that might give me a hint?

Comment: Have you created a certificates/profiles by yourself, or you've imported it to your mac?

Comment: I let XCode handle the certificates, they seem up to date (I was building fine up until I upgraded to XCode 8 the other day).  Otherwise I tried generating the profiles through the development portal, then imported them, I've no idea how to create them myself other than that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fixed it.  I suddenly noticed XCTest was being copied over to the phone.  It looks like my testing target is also being installed?  I did not think that would happen when building and running my app, code signing was not required before, it certainly wasn't set.

I set the testing target to also Automatically manage signing and now it works!  I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Dude I was trying to solve this problem since 10 hours. You helped me a lot. In my case something was wrong with the test signing. So I changed it to no signing and then back on which it should be. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it after I deselected the 'Automatically manage signing' in the testing Target.

Comment: That fixed it for me!

Comment: oh you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Delete DerivedData /`Finder` -> `Go` -> (holding Options key) `Library` -> `Developer` -> `Xcode` -> delete DerivedData folder/
2. Set provisioning profile to `Automatic`
3. Set Release to `Distribution` rather than `Developer`
4. `Clean`.

This pattern worked for me, hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8.3.3:

Had the same problem.

tried deleting Derived Data, cleaning project, changed dev team back and forth, manually setting the prov profiles, nothing helped.
Fixed it in the end by restarting Xcode :/

Answer (score 0):

try this command in terminal

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```